# Issue on Filtering Table in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I have a problem on filtering in React and MUI.
My problem if I add a row first and then filter after that, filter doesn't work anymore.
Meanwhile if I don't add a row and filter immediately it works.

Steps to reproduce:

1. on page load, click "Add new rule" button.
2. Click filter and it will open a filter menu
3. Choose "Attribute" in Columns field, choose "Equals" in Operator field and type "products" in Value field

It should show the products column however it isn't showing it, it just shows the new blank row.

CODESANDBOX -----> [CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-khayyam-zv6y1d?file=/edit/table/index.js)

```
const operatorFunctions = new Map([
  [
    "equals",
    (dataValue, value) => dataValue?.toLowerCase() === value?.toLowerCase()
  ],
  [
    "starts_with",
    (dataValue, value) =>
      dataValue?.toLowerCase().startsWith(value?.toLowerCase())
  ]
]);

export const customFilter = (filter, data) => {
  if (!data) return [];

  return data.filter((row) =>
    filter.every(({ value = "", operator = "", columns = "" }) => {
      if (!value) return true;
      if (!operatorFunctions.has(operator)) return false;
      return operatorFunctions.get(operator)(row[columns]?.toString(), value);
    })
  );
};
```

Comment: I've filtered, added a row then filtered, started from empty and added a row then filtered... each time it seemed the filtering was functional. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the description. Can you [edit] to clarify more precisely what the issue is, or more accurate reproduction steps?

Comment: I didn't find any problem. it filters before and after adding a row

Comment: Yes, that is one of the ways I tested. It is filtering the rows. Well, rows are being removed/non-rendered, so I'm assuming the UI is filtering row data as per what you've coded.

Comment: It appears so, yes. When I (1) click "add new rule", (2) click filter, and (3) select "attribute", "equals", then enter "products", the UI reduces the rows to *just* the new row I added. What are you expecting the result to be?

Comment: Ah, so it *is* actually filtering, but just *incorrectly*. Ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <CustomTableRow
    key={row.id}
    row={row}
    index={index}
    arrayHelpers={arrayHelpers}
  />
```

The issue is with the index prop which is passed to your CustomTableRow component. The index value should be based on the index of the item in `values.row` instead of the index from your filter result. A possible solution would be:

```
 <CustomTableRow
    key={row.id}
    row={row}
    index={values.rows.findIndex(({id}) => id === row.id)}
    arrayHelpers={arrayHelpers}
  />
```

Comment: I believe this is correct. The reason is likely the name attribute passed to the `FastField` component as I suspect this is what Formik uses to grab the field value out of its values object. The index is used to create this name attribute.

Comment: This doesn't work still. Maybe if you can fork my codesandbox?

Comment: Tested and it works [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-grass-qtn9s0?file=/edit/table/index.js)

Comment: Comments are meant to ask for clarification on the current problem or suggested solution. If you have a question for a different unrelated problem, post a new question.